# How to change the color of SharePoint 2013 SuiteBar?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css, custom-masterpage, branding

I have a custom master page and referring a custom CSS file, which is successfully implemented. but the suitebar is still referring the corev15.css file and i have tried changing color of the suite bar from my css file, but nothing happens. I have referenced the CSS in my masterpage as well.

CSS I USED

```
.ms-verticalAlignMiddle{
color: #444 !important;
}
.ms-tableCell{
color: #444 !important;
}
#suitebarleft{
background-color: #444 !important;
}
```

Masterpage edits
added this in the head

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/sites/search/Style Library/intranet.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server"/>
```

and then this

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server"/>-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/sites/search/Style Library/intranet.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server"/>-->
```

I just want to change the color of the suitebar from blue to black.

When I inspect the page I have 
[image: This is the default view i get]

Then when I strike out I can see the changes I made
[image: This is the after I strike out]

Now how do I implement this.

Comment: Is the other style getting applied? Can you check the browser console and see if your styles are getting overridded by out of the box styles?

Comment: @AmalHashim yes I just inspected the elements and edited the description.

Comment: That is very strange. So you can see Intranet.css in the console?

Comment: @AmalHashim yes I can see it. the entire page calls the intranet.css, but the suite bar calls the corev15.css. and doest even let me override it, I even used the !important tag in my CSS

Comment: Have you tried placing the style directly on the master page?

Comment: how do I do that @AmalHashim

Comment: Just before `</head>`.. add `<style>#suiteBarLeft...</style>`

Comment: In your CSS selector you do not have the proper capitalization.  You want `#suiteBarLeft` not `#suitebarleft`.

Comment: @DylanCristy  I added the tags in the masterpage, and change the capitalization in the CSS file and it worked, problem solved. I totally forgot that CSS is case sensitive. Thank you guys alot, please submit your comments as answers so that I can upvote them, would be helpful for others.

Comment: @AmalHashim I added the tags in the masterpage, and change the capitalization in the CSS file and it worked, problem solved. I totally forgot that CSS is case sensitive. Thank you guys alot, please submit your comments as answers so that I can upvote them, would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS you posted, you do not have the proper capitalization.

You want:

```
#suiteBarLeft
```

instead of

```
#suitebarleft
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the CSS directly into the master page

Just before `</head>`

Add `<style>#suiteBarLeft...</style>`